# Is it possible to pause an LXC container and reboot the host without losing state?

Tags: linux, lxc

I have a few processes running in tmux inside a container made with `lxc-create` and I'm wondering if there is a command to "freeze" the container, reboot the host machine, and restore the container to the state it was in?

I noticed `lxc-freeze` and `lxc-checkpoint` but I'm not sure if these will work the way I expect (with a full reboot of the host), or if there are better solutions for this.

Comment: Take a look at https://criu.org/